# Regular expression not working in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I write the regular expression in nginx but it does not work. Why?

```
location /profil/(cancel_email|activation) {
```

If write the following, instead

```
location /profil/cancel_email {
location /profil/activation {
```

it works, but i want use reglar expression

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a regexp match symbol ~ to your location directive, like that:

```
location ~ ^/profil/(cancel_email|activation) {
  ...
}
```

Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location